# Porque aparecen caracteres no deseados en mi salida?

Tags: c++, windows

Hola tengo este codigo que se ejucuta y compila bien pero me agraga caracteres que no deberian estar ahi

codigo:

```
void wout(char* text){
    HANDLE hcoln;
    hcoln = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    DWORD juo=strlen(text);
    LPDWORD iuo=0;
    WriteFile(hcoln, text, juo, iuo, NULL);
    delete text;
}
void winp(void* text){
    HANDLE hcoln;
    hcoln = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    DWORD juo=200;
    LPDWORD iuo=0;
    ReadFile(hcoln, text, juo, iuo, NULL);
    text=0;
}
int main(){
    char text;
    while(0==0){
    winp(&text);
    wout(&text);
    }
}
```

La salida es

```
Hola mundo como estas?

Hola mundo como estas?

la mundo como estas?

la mundo como estas?

la mundo como estas?

la mundo como estas?
```

gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Qué salida deseas obtener?

Comment: Solamente "Hola mundo cómo estás?" una vez y no "la mundo cómo estás?" Varias veces al ingresar  una nueva cadena o precionar la tecla enter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Básicamente yo diría que tu problema es que estás pisando memoria sin control:

Fíjate que la variable `text` es de tipo `char` en la función `main`, esto quiere decir que esa variable tiene espacio para almacenar únicamente un caracter:

```
int main() {
    char text;
```

Sin embargo usas esa variable para almacenar una cadena de caracteres:

```
ReadFile(hcoln, text, juo, iuo, NULL);
```

Esto hace que se escriba en posiciones de memoria que no pertenecen a `text` sino a otras variables de tu aplicación (variables declaradas en la pila en este caso). El resultado suele ser un comportamiento errático en la aplicación, que es lo que te está sucediendo a ti.

Prueba a convertir `text` en un buffer con capacidad para almacenar caracteres:

```
int main() {
    char text[1000]; // Podrá almacenar hasta 999 caracteres
```

---

Si repasamos la documentación de [`ReadFile`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile) encontramos lo siguiente:

> lpNumberOfBytesRead
> A pointer to the variable that receives the number of bytes read when using a synchronous hFile parameter. ReadFile sets this value to zero before doing any work or error checking.
>
> Use NULL for this parameter if this is an asynchronous operation to avoid potentially erroneous results.
>
> **This parameter can be NULL only when the lpOverlapped parameter is not NULL.**

Es decir, que este parámetro no puede ser `NULL` si el parámetro `lpOverlapped` es igualmente `NULL`.

Si repasamos tu llamada encontramos lo siguiente:

```
DWORD juo=200;
LPDWORD iuo=0;

ReadFile(hcoln, text, juo, iuo, NULL);
//                         ~~~  ~~~~
//                          1    2
```

Donde:

1. lpNumberOfBytesRead. Le estás pasando un 0, pero el prefijo `LP` de `LPDWORD` quiere decir *Long Pointer*, es decir, estamos ante un puntero cuyo valor es 0, es decir, `NULL`
2. lpOverlapped. Es NULL directamente

Estás haciendo justo algo que desaconsejan en la propia documentación de `ReadFile`.

En el caso de [`WriteFile`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-writefile) sucede exactamente lo mismo, estás pasando `NULL` a ambos parámetros y es algo que en la documentación te dicen que no lo hagas.

Comment: Hola, hice lo que me pediste pero no funciona aun, al parecer los cararcteres qu me aparecen al presionar la tecla enter son parte de la ultima cadena,

Por ejemplo:
Si escribo HOLA MUNDO todo va bine pero si escribo Hola Mun Sale:

Hola mun
o

Que podria hacer para liberar la memoria del char o de las winp o wout?

Comment: En el caso del parametro lpOverlapped la documentacion dice lo siguiente:

Se requiere un puntero a una estructura OVERLAPPED si el parámetro hFile se abrió con FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED ; de lo contrario, este parámetro puede ser NULL .

Mi parametro hFile no se abrio con la bandera FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED  y es por esta razon que el parametro lpOverlapped es NULL

Comment: @Jose así es, lo que estás haciendo mal es dejar el parámetro `lpNumberOfBytesRead` a NULL. La documentación dice que ambos no pueden ser NULL a la vez, pero no te está diciendo que cambies uno en concreto... si en tu caso uno debe ser NULL, está claro que debes cambiar el otro